# Clustering with constraint on minimum size of cluster

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, constraint

I have dataset of $n$ objects, I want to cluster them according to correlation and I want to divide the dataset into groups of similar objects of sizes not less than 50 - because I use clustering for estimation of parameters. I can not throw out small clusters - these objects come from medical sources and each of them is important. I can not just use 1 cluster - objects may be seriously dissimilar due to "batch effects". Is there a strategy to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DBSCAN clustering algorithm](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3001460.3001507) allows you to specify a minimum number of data points per cluster. It also labels dots that it cannot cluster with the given parameter settings as "noise", so you can examine those separately.

Since you also set the [hierarchical-clustering](/questions/tagged/hierarchical-clustering) tag, you may also be interested in DBSCAN's newer hierarchical version [HDBSCAN](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-37456-2_14).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to come up with some solution like "manual joining items from small clusters to bigger ones", but this one is much, much better!